# Split Email Address In Sas

Tags: sas

anyone know how to split the email address in SAS ? this is the case:

```
happy_new_year@gmail.commakannasi@yahoo.co.idnasigoreng@abc.net
```

then split above text into:

```
happy_new_year@gmail.com|makannasu@yahoo.co.id|nasigoreng@abc.net
```

until now I haven't got best solution how to split it.

thanks

Comment: What you'll want to do is get all the possible extensions of the emails (.com, .co.id, .net, etc) and traverse across your String until you find one of them. Then split the String at that point, and move on until you run into the end of the String. I know nothing of SAS so I can't help you farther than that, sorry. It could quickly become tricky like @Joe said, though.

Comment: I would say there isn't a good solution to that general problem.  You could use a regex to identify likely stopping points (.com .net etc.) but now that there are far more TLDs, that's not really feasible; and even if you limited it to the common ones, you would get all sorts of false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as the comments say, this is can be tricky with the large number of .* TLDs.  Not to mention you could have a tld with the first letter of the next address that looked like another tld.  I.E. if .xy and .xyz are both tlds, `me@here.xyzed@here.com` would be ambigous.  Is it `me@here.xy|zed@here.com` or `me@here.xyz|ed@here.com`?

That said I would start to approach it this way.

```
%let tlds = .com .net .edu .blah .fu .bar;

data _null_;
format str $2000.;
str = "bob@here.comchris@xyz.blahme@hrm.fu";

tlds = "&tlds";
format tld $4.;
do i=1 to countw(tlds);
    tld = scan(tlds,i);
    str = tranwrd(str,strip(tld),strip(tld)||"|");
end;
put str;
run;
```

Returns

```
bob@here.com|chris@xyz.blah|me@hrm.fu|
```

Add logic like additional tlds or new logic as needed.